# Point an IP to android webview app

Tags: android, apache, laravel, android-webview, digital-ocean

I have a digital ocean droplet running apache on Ubuntu hosting my laravel project. I also have an app with a webview which displays the laravel site. However when a password reset or verification email is sent and a user clicks the link in a web browser, my laravel site shows up on the browser and surfing continues on the browser. I would like that upon clicking on any such tokens which begin with my IP, the user should be redirected back to my webview app where he or she should continue with the password reset and login. Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing this you have to add **Deep linking** feature ofAndroid Application.
If any Deep Linked Uri is encountered the Application will be oppened.

You Can Learn **Deep Linking** [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)

For Further References :

1.https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

2.https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

3.https://developers.helpshift.com/android/deep-linking/

4.https://android.jlelse.eu/deep-linking-in-android-46bc61bd9750

Comment: Hey @Tomin B I know I'm pushing it but is it possible to set the link to inactive if it is attempted on a non-android device like a computer??

Comment: @Dyvynh IDont Kow abot that.Sorry